# Error in usage of stateless function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use the stateless component like this -

```
const EditStoreComponent = function () {
    return (
      <div>New panel Content!</div>
    );
};
```

it works fine. But when the usage is like the following (I am using react-bootstrap)-

```
const EditStoreComponent = function () {
return (
  <form>
      <FieldGroup
        id="formControlsText"
        type="text"
        label="Store name"
        placeholder="Enter Store Name" />
  </form>
);
```

};

FieldGroup Component is also a stateless function -

```
function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={id}>
      <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl {...props} />
     {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
    </FormGroup>
 );
}
```

it gives the following error - 
`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of EditStoreComponent`.

I am unable to figure out why this is happening. 
Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is `FieldGroup` defined?

Comment: Can you show where you render `EditStoreComponent`?

Comment: FieldGroup is a separate stateless function which I have used from React-Bootstrap. Below is the link. Also i have mentioned that function above in the code. 
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I have used EditStoreComponent something like this 
`panelContent = <EditStoreComponent />;` and I don't think it has some problem because it works fine.

Comment: add a `console.log(FieldGroup)` right before `return` inside `EditStoreComponent` and see whether you're getting something.

Comment: @free-soul it logs the FieldGroup function in plain javascript 

`function FieldGroup(_ref) {
            var id = _ref.id
              , label = _ref.label;
            return React.createElement(FormGroup, {
                controlId: id
            }, React.createElement(ControlLabel, null , label));
        }`

which is expected output.